# Magento extension not working in custom theme

Tags: magento

I have integrated social login extension, It works proper in magento default theme, but not working with my mtcepora theme.

Any help please.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where are the template and layout files for the social login extension? Are they in `app/design/frontend/base/default` or are they somewhere else? If elsewhere, move them to the base folder and as long as there are no bugs in the extension itself it should work for all themes.

Comment: The other possibility is that something in your custom theme may be interfering with the extension.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?